# RPI root partition lost PARTUUID and can't boot

Tags: filesystems, raspberry-pi, fdisk, uuid

So I cloned a RPI sd card so I could run the same system at home and at work. The sd cards were slightly different sizes so after I ran dd I had to run resize2fs and fsck. If I boot the Pi with this I get dropped to an emergency shell and I can mount the root partition and it works.

The problem: I need this to run headless and I cant mount the root partition every time it starts. When the Pi boots it looks for PARTUUID="ceafa322-02". If I could change the pi to boot from the new root UUID or something that would be fine, but I don't know the boot process on one of these. What I have been trying to do is modify the partition with fdisk, but I dont know how an identifier like 0xXXXXXXXX translates to ceafa322-02 as a PARTUUID

What is the best course of action? I can nuke the installment, but I am almost determined at this point.

Answer (score 0):

On MBR-partitioned disks, there are no real 128-bit UUIDs for partitions specified in the partition table; the MBR partition table is way too small for that. Instead, the PARTUUID is created by adding a dash and a two-digit partition number to a 32-bit disk identifier.

So in your `PARTUUID="ceafa322-02"`, the `-02` part is simply the partition number, and `ceafa322` is the disk identifier. It is in hexadecimal, which is often indicated by prefixing the hexadecimal number with `0x`.

So, when setting the disk identifier with `fdisk`, you just specify it as `0xceafa322`.

Comment: Soo, I changed the identifier in fdisk to 0xceafa322 and it wiped the data from the disk and all blkid reports is: /dev/sda2: PTUUID="ceafa322" PTTYPE="dos". Is there something I need to do to get it to retain the rest of the partition data?

Comment: Looks like you used `fdisk /dev/sda2` rather than `fdisk /dev/sda`, and it wrote an extra partition table over the beginning of the first partition. You should always use the whole-disk device (e.g. `/dev/sda`) with `fdisk`.

Comment: That I did, its been a while since I used fdisk. I reimaged the sd card and ran fdisk /dev/sda. I could change the PARTUUID of the pis vfat boot partition that wrote fine, but the ext4 partition showed no PARTUUID and still did not boot. I did fix the installation by changing root=mmcblk0p2 in the boot.txt and recompiling, but I am still curious about the PARTUUIDs